# Passing a text string via jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, iteration

Let's say I've got a list with some values

```
<li>#1</li>
<li>#2</li>
...
```

and I want to take those values to put them into some `<span>` elements. Whats the best case to iterate these steps and to get every single value into an single `<span>` element? 
I've been trying

```
var str = $( "li" ).text();
$( "span" ).html( str );
```

which only gives me the whole `<li>` values into one `<span>` element.

Comment: Your problem is the logic. `var str` is one object, whereas you have multiple objects(`li`). Use `.each()` http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.html()`'s receiver function to get your job done,

```
$("li").html(function(i,html){
  return $('<span>',{text : html});
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly37T/1/)

---

Try to use .text()'s receiver function and .eq() function to get your job done,

```
$("span").text(function(i,text){
  return $('li').eq(i).text();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ly37T/)

Answer (score 2):

if you mean you wanna wrap the values into a span, then try this:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).html('<span>'+$(this).html()+'</span>');
});
```

if you want to get all of the value's of li's and then put them into one single `span`, then try this one:

```
var value='';
$('li').each(function(){
    value=value+' '+$(this).html();
});
$('span').html(value);
```